# Responsive image resizing with inline-block property

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I'm using inline-block to create an image gallery, with each image having its own div and width. I'm having a problem when I resize the page, the images adjust to the screen width, which is good, but by the time I get down to around 400px (the mobile area), the images become extremely too small.

How can I ensure that the images maintain a good size regardless of the screen width?

```css
*  { 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.container {
  width:80%;
}

section.portfolio {
  background:
}

section.portfolio .col {
  background:;
  width:23.3%; 
  padding:10px;
  margin: 5%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

section.portfolio .col img {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

img {
  max-width:100%;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="portfolio">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://images3.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PDP_HERO/843384_001_C_PREM/air-max-1-ultra-flyknit-shoe.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://images3.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PDP_HERO/843384_001_C_PREM/air-max-1-ultra-flyknit-shoe.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <img src="http://images3.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PDP_HERO/843384_001_C_PREM/air-max-1-ultra-flyknit-shoe.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use media queries and set a width of 300px (or whatever you prefer)

```
@media screen and  (min-width:320px) and (max-width: 480px) { 
    section.portfolio .col {
      width:300px; 

        }
}
```

pen is  [here](http://codepen.io/repzeroworld/pen/NpVqdz)

Also refer to https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ for various mobile dimension

Comment: This worked many thanks! In addition to media queries for mobile, I will add media queries based on content.

Answer (score 0):

Give `position:relative` to your parent div, and `position:absolute` to child element, use code like:

```
<div class="col" style="position:relative">

          <img src="http://images3.nike.com/is/image/DotCom/PDP_HERO/843384_001_C_PREM/air-max-1-ultra-flyknit-shoe.jpg" style="position:absolute">

    </div>
```

This might solve your problem.

Comment: This didn't work. Perhaps it would be a good idea to add media queries based on content, as well as my device breakpoints? I'm reluctant to do this purely for aesthetic reasons, to me it looks weird seeing images decrease in size then suddenly increase.